# How to access a variable/return value(of a method) in view, declared while creating a new record in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, r

I am trying to call some R functions using RinRuby from rails. I have created a method, having R script and associated variables. The work flow is like, user uploads a data file, the app tries to write and save a copy of the datafile in the public folder. The required data is then extracted, mapped to R variables and passed to the R interpreter. R returns the result which would be displayed in the view in the form of graph. Everything is working fine. I can see R returning the output from the log. But I am not able to display results in the View.

I am calling the method(having R script) from the create action and saving the returned output in an instance variable. I am not able to figure out how to use this instance variable, since its not in any view associated actions. I cant even use before_filter option because I want this method to be called after the new and create action. I dont want to save anything related to the datafile in the database except some input in the user form.

can anyone suggest a way to display the output in the view. Codes are available here:
https://github.com/kumarsaurabh20/PlotApp/blob/master/app/controllers/plots_controller.rb

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.11.

Comment: remove the 'return' from line 163 and try again. In Ruby, last evaluated statement is the return value.

Comment: Thanx.. for pointing out Syed..I corrected it. 
I used format.html { render :html => @result } and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to be exposed only to the next action then use the flash.

```
if @savedfile
  self.dataExtract(name)
  @result =  self.calTheta(id, name)
  logger.debug @result.to_s
  format.html { 
    flash[:notice] = 'Calibration data file is successfully saved.'
    flash[:result] = @result
    redirect_to :controller => "plots", :action => "index" 
  }
  format.xml  { render :xml => @plot, :status => :created, :location => @plot }
else
 ...
```

Comment: Thanx for your comment Guy. Instead of flash I used format.html { render :html => @result } and it worked. I will give flash also a try.

Comment: flash giving me:
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
ActionController::Session::CookieStore::CookieOverflow

Comment: yeah flash (sessions) by default are using cookie as the storage and cookies can't handle much data, you can change your storage from cookie to other storage systems that can handle more data. (i.e redis)